# Traefik V2 & Cloudflare : SSL error subdomain ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: ssl, proxy, cloudflare, lets-encrypt, traefik

I want to deploy a Traefik with SSL using a wildcard certificate.

```
My domain is: sub.domain.com
My applications are :  
traefik.sub.domain.com
portainer.sub.domain.com
```

I want to create for each application an entry in the cloudflare dns.
For that I made :

A -> sub- > 177.171.8.109

CNAME -> portainer.sub -> sub.domain.com

CNAME -> traefik.sub -> sub.domain.com

Traefik starts normally without errors.
The nslookup command also returns a correct answer.

The problem is that when I access my portainer.sub.domain.com applications, I get an error like: `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

No certificate visible in the "Connection not secure" lock location

```
FYI: If I delete my two entries and do a CNAME: 
CNAME -> *.sub -> sub.domain.com
```

then I have access to my applications, but I lose all the advantage of the cloudflare proxy which does not support proxification via *....

Thanks for your help!

Traefik logs :

```
time="2021-03-12T21:33:33Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [sub.domain.com, *.sub.domain.com] acme: Validations succeeded; requesting certificates"
time="2021-03-12T21:33:38Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [sub.domain.com] Server responded with a certificate."
time="2021-03-12T21:33:38Z" level=debug msg="Certificates obtained for domains [sub.domain.com *.sub.domain.com]" providerName=mydnschallenge.acme
```

Traefik configuration :
https://pastebin.com/4uGftcys

Answer (score 4):

Due to cloudflare policy(free subscription), it is not possible to do sub.sub-domain.domain.fr
You can only do sub.domain.fr

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an idea...

If you are trying something like this https://technotim.live/posts/traefik-portainer-ssl/

- Cloudflare free-tier
- local SSLs for Sub-Sub-Domain

I've had the same `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

For me the trick was to make sure the **local IPs** accessing Traefik were allowed on my HTTPS/Websecure Entrypoint like so:

`- --entrypoints.https.forwardedHeaders.trustedIPs=$CLOUDFLARE_IPS,$LOCAL_IPS`

These variables are just IP-lists like: 173.245.48.0/20,103.21.244.0/22,103.22.200.0/22,...